# Interpreting FFT background noice

Tags: acoustics, fourier-transform, signal-processing, noise

There is some construction down my street and I think the drills are putting off a high pitch noise so I downloaded a spectrum analyzer. they have an FFT plot here:

The "57-dB-A" I guess is the decibals of the noise at the current time. They have a scale and 57 is within the "normal room noise". Heavy traffic is 80 db-A.

Comment: Can you provide the corresponding plot when the equipment is not operating?

Comment: Its 24/7.  Can you interpret the x and Y axis?

Comment: If it's doing what it should, X is frequency and Y is power spectral density of sound pressure level (or something similar).

Comment: Note that +57 dB(SPL) is probably what they had in mind for normal room noise. 0 dB(SPL) is roughly the threshold of hearing. -70 dB SPL is very very quiet. Are you sure your microphone was actually connected to the digitizing/recording device?

Comment: I guess I am asking for an intuitive explanaiton for someone who isn't familiar with frequency and power spectral.

Comment: A decibel scale (vertical axis) only gives *relative* loudness at different frequencies. Unless you know what $0$dB means, you can't really "measure" anything, except that most of the sound energy seems to be at low frequencies. The markings on the axis don't seem to be consistent with the standard dBA scale which does have a defined value of $0$dBA. FWIW 57dBA is at a level described as "quiet daytime urban" (outdoors) or "dishwasher operating in next room" (indoors) which doesn't seem excessive. Try downloading a different spectrum analyser - that one looks broken to me.

Answer (score 0):

The horizontal axis is "frequency". Imagine all sound is made up of a mixture of frequencies - a bit like someone hitting all the keys of a piano at the same time. The spectrum analyzer does some clever mathematics to determine what keys were being hit, and how hard.

The horizontal (X) axis of your plot is frequency (in Hz, with the 'k' meaning 'kHz'). There is quite a lot of low frequency noise - below 500 Hz. Then it gets a lot more quiet, but there is a distinct peak at 4.5 kHz. That is a rather high-pitched sound - and it's sufficiently louder than the other sounds that your ears might be able to pick it up as a separate sound.

There is a "roll off" of the sound starting at 18.5 kHz. This could be the frequency response of your microphone, or attenuation of sound by air.

The vertical axis is calibrated in dB. That is a logarithmic power scale - when the dB increases by 10, there is 10x more power in the sound. I don't know what your "0 dB" point is - that's a bit arbitrary.

The dBa scale is the "acoustic noise" scale. This is a scale that gives different weights to sounds of different frequencies (to get a "equally irritating" sound level you need a different power level at different frequencies).

I think the "57 dBa" measure is intended to indicate the apparent sound level. This requires some absolute calibration of microphone sensitivity - not sure whether that was actually done for your measurement. The plot has a light blue "band" that catches the highest and lowest value of power observed in each frequency band - those fluctuations are natural when you have random noise as input.

Comment: Thank you. Just to confirm as I go up on the Y axis I would hear higher pitched sounds?  Like a whistler or dog whistler (that I can't hear) would be higher up on the Y axis? So if they have a drill with a high pitched sound -40 on the Y axis could be it?  Right now I am sitting at work in the Y axis is is at -70 when the x axis is at 0.

Comment: No - higher pitched noise is further to the right on the X axis. I think the "blip" at 4.5 kHz is the high pitched noise you are hearing (although that may just be a noise spike - the "envelope" doesn't seem to be particularly higher there than at other frequencies).

Comment: I am confused now.  You stated "but there is a distinct peak at 4.5 kHz. That is a rather high-pitched sound - and it's sufficiently louder than the other sounds that your ears might be able to pick it up as a separate sound." What do you mean again?

Comment: Do you see the "blip" I am talking about? The yellow line goes up just after the 4k mark. That is a "high" frequency that you can still hear. I'm just not sure if it is distinct enough - the light blue "band" around the yellow line is called the "envelope" - when you measure the sound multiple times you keep getting a different answer, but always within the envelope. The envelope doesn't have an obvious bump at 4.5 kHz so I'm not sure whether the blip I see there is "real" and could be heard, or "noise on the measurement".